# tengo un problema con iniciar sesion en codeigniter

Tags: bootstrap, codeigniter

mi problema ya tengo el modelo controlador probe ya conexion con base de datos y todo pero a la hora de iniciar sesion no loguea:

**modelo class user**

```
class User extends CI_Model{
  public function getUser($email = ''){

    $result = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE email = ' "  . $email . " ' LIMIT 1 ");

    if ($result->num_rows() > 0) {
      return $result->row();
    }else{
      return    null;
    }   
  }
}
```

aca el controlador

```
class Login extends CI_Controller{
    public function index(){
        $email = $this->input->post('email');
        $password = $this->input->post('password');
        $this->load->model('user');
        $fila = $this->user->getUser($email);
        if ($fila != null) {
            if ($fila->password == $password) {
                $data = array(
                    'email' => $email,
                    'id' => $fila->id,
                    'login' => TRUE
                );
                $this->session->set_userdata($data);
            }
            else {
                header("location: " . base_url());
            }
        }
        else {
            header("location: " . base_url());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: si imprimes el query que te sale? Coloca esto antes del if en el modelo y checa si el query es el correct `echo $this->db->last_query(); die();`

Comment: perdon por la respuesta estaba de viaje mira vi eso pero me sale esto:SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE email = ' tito@gmail.com ' LIMIT 1

Comment: si ejecutas ese query en mysql si lo ejecuta? es el resultado esperado? por lo que veo tiene un espacio en blanco antes de **tito@gmail.com** tendrias que utilizar `trim($email)` para borrar esos espacios

Answer (score 0):

Quizás te falte cargar la librería session en el controlador, intenta y me avisas tengo un codigo de login en CI que actualmente esta funcionando, saludos

```
$this->load->library('session');
```